# Output of a function used as an input for another

Tags: python, python-3.x

Last question about this topic.

I didn't add the output as its not the issue rather then passing of the output. Basically the final output of each function is a list. I am running into a problem. So this is the code I have

```
def mean(studentp_file):

    li = []
    for line in studentp_file:
        nameless = line[1:14]


        for l in range(len(nameless)):
            answer = sum(nameless)/len(nameless)
        li.append(answer)


    li.insert(0,"Needie Seagoon")
    li.insert(2,"Eccles")
    li.insert(4,"Bluebottle")
    li.insert(6,"Henry Crun")
    li.insert(8,"Minnie Bannister")
    li.insert(10,"Hercules Grytpype-Thynne")
    li.insert(12,"Count Jim Moriarty")
    li.insert(14, "Major Dennis Bloodnok")

    mean_li = li

    return mean_li


passing_file = normalise("DB.csv.", "units.csv")

mean(passing_file)

"""

This function will print out the final mean average percentile for each student over
their computer science degree.

"""

def final(mean_li):

~ wanted to see if the code worked.~
    print(mean_li)

mean_list = mean(studentp_file)

final(mean_list)
```

The problem I am having is passing the variable mean_li into the new function final(). I get the error mean_list = mean(student_file) is not defined? I was able to pass output of another function into the previous function but for some reason I can't do it here.

Any help would be great.

Comment: the indentation makes the question impossible to answer.

Comment: Elaborate, I will try and make it easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the error is `studentp_file is not defined`. The variable `studentp_file` is only valid inside the definition of function `mean`. Outside of that function, you are using `passing_file` variable. This should work

```
mean_list = mean(passing_file)
```

Comment: Legend, makes sense when I read through it again, forgot the normalise() was set to passing_file. Thanks, Again